# Cannot parse string to time with timezone offset included RFC3339 with seemingly contradictory errors

Tags: parsing, go, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I am using Golang and time.Time to Parse a given string into a time object.

Using RFC3339 and `time.Parse` here is an example of my code:

```
t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-08-08T00:22:44Z07:00")
if err != nil {
   return nil, err
}
```

I get the follow errors.

When I include timezone offset I am getting:

```
ERRO[0002] parsing time "2020-08-08T00:22:44Z07:00": extra text: 07:00
```

When I don't include the timezone offset I am getting:

```
ERRO[0002] parsing time "2020-08-08T00:15:36" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "Z07:00"
```

How do I avoid this issue when parsing time into a structured object?

Comment: `2020-08-08T00:22:44Z07:00` is not a valid RFC3339 date. Try `2020-08-08T00:22:44Z`, `2020-08-08T00:22:44+07:00`, or `2020-08-08T00:22:44-07:00`

Comment: interesting that golang time.RFC3339 ==  "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"

Comment: That's the template. That doesn't mean it's a valid timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presence of the character `Z` in the Go `time.RFC3339` constant `"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"` does **not** mean that a date conforming to the pattern is supposed to include a `Z` followed by the time zone offset.

In fact, a date with `Z` followed by anything else is not a valid RFC3339 date. Hence, your first error `extra text: 07:00`

The `Z` stands for "Zulu Time", i.e. UTC time zone. From the RFC3339 specs:

> ```
>   Z           A suffix which, when applied to a time, denotes a UTC
>               offset of 00:00; often spoken "Zulu" from the ICAO
>               phonetic alphabet representation of the letter "Z".
> ```

So the `Z` **alone** is already providing the time zone information, that is, UTC.

As @Flimzy noted in the comments, `2020-08-08T00:22:44Z` would be a valid RFC3339 date.

```
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-08-08T00:22:44Z")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t) // 2020-08-08 00:22:44 +0000 UTC
```

Now, if you read the RFC3339 standard further, you see this definition:

> ```
> time-zone       = "Z" / time-numoffset
> time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour [[":"] time-minute]
> ```

Which means that the time zone part of the date is **either** a `Z` or the offset. Clearly, since the `Z` already represents the offset `00:00`, you can't have one more `+/-HH:mm` offset in the same date string.

But this also means that `Z` **or** the `+/-HH:mm` must be present. So if you remove both of them, you get your second error: `cannot parse "" as "Z07:00"`

The parser is attempting to read the `"2020-08-08T00:15:36"` string as RFC3339 so it expects either a `Z` or an offset after the seconds (or milliseconds, if any).

---

In conclusion, the `Z07:00` in the Go `time.RFC3339` pattern is just a representation of the fact that the date string is supposed to include a time zone. A valid RFC3339 date string must include either `Z` or the offset.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for anyone else Googling these terms and coming here. Golang shares the standard as a hard-coded golang time.RFC3339 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" which may throw people off.